# How to .remove all matches in a Python list?

Tags: python, list

If I have a bit of Python like:

```
n = [1, 3, 5, 1]
n.remove(1)
print n
```

n will return `[3, 5, 1]` because `.remove()` quits after it finds its first match. What could I do to return just `[3, 5]`, having found *all* matches (or in this case, all the `1`s)?

Answer (score 11):

If creating a new list is fine:

```
n = [x for x in n if x != 1]
```

Of course you could also use slice assignment to modify the list in place:

```
n[:] = [x for x in n if x != 1]
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken and there's some interpreter optimization going on, that's not technically an in place operation.  You construct a list in a new region in memory, then copy it in to the memory footprint of the original list.

Comment: Yeah, there is a temporary copy made for the slice assignment.  When I say "in place" I mean that `n` is still referencing the same list (with modified contents), rather than having `n` bound to a completely different list.  It really only matters if there are other references to the list.

Answer (score 2):

use filter function

```
n = [1, 3, 5, 1]
filter(lambda a:a is not 1,n)
[3,5]
```

**edit**

```
n = [1, 3, 5, 1]
filter(lambda a:a != 1,n)
[3,5]
```

Comment: `is not` tests (non)identity, not (in)equality.  You want `a != 1` instead-- it only works on `1` by fluke, basically (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers), for example.)

Comment: fixed, didn't knew about identity of variables, will take more care, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simple [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) -

```
>>> n = [1, 3, 5, 1]
>>> n = [e for e in n if e != 1]
>>> n
[3, 5]
```

If you wanted to remove more than one elements -

```
>>> g = [1,3]
>>> n = [e for e in n if e not in g]
>>> n
[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how I'd normally do this, but:

```
n = [1, 3, 5, 1]
REMOVECHAR = 1
while REMOVECHAR in n:
    n.remove(REMOVECHAR)
# could also do:
# while 1:
#     try: n.remove(REMOVECHAR)
#     except ValueError as e: break
```

If I were doing it, I would use a list comp to make a new list.

```
n = [1,3,5,1]
REMOVECHAR = 1
nn = [element for element in n if element != REMOVECHAR]
```

Comment: Why have you capitalised `REMOVECHAR`?

Comment: Because I'm using it as a constant, which are written in UPPERCASE as per [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) though I suppose technically I should have used `REMOVE_CHAR` :P

Comment: `try\except` version is better, as you don't have to do the O(n) membership check every iteration.  Though still, inefficient since you are still traversing every element that precedes a match even if you've already checked it until all instances are removed.

Comment: But less obvious to a new coder who is asking how to remove all members of a list, which is why I presented it as an alternate implementation in comments :). I'd wager that `try/except` is faster than the list comprehension too except perhaps for very large lists with many occurrences of `REMOVECHAR`

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate backwards through the list and pop elements that match.

```
def remove_all_in_place(target, sequence):
    cursor = len(target) - 1
    while cursor >= 0:
        if sequence[cursor] == target:
            sequence.pop(cursor)
        cursor -= 1
```

List comprehensions *might* be faster since they are optimized, but  they aren't in-place operations.  For native Python implementations, I think this would be fastest, as well as being true in-place.

Comment: I've always followed the rule "Don't operate on a list while iterating on it." Does your `lst.pop(needle)` actually work safely while iterating through `lst`?

Comment: That's why I go backwards through it.  Going forwards would change the indexes of future elements making things more difficult.